# How to get rid of sub-menu underline

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a problem which isn't really big or something,but it annoys me as hell.The problem is underlining of child elements of my sub-menu,and what i mean by that is https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pMNK.jpg .Yep,that right there drives me crazy.It shows instantly when i hover on my parent element,in my menu.I started to coding like 2 weeks ago,so my question might be stupid,but please if somebody know how to remove it and fix my padding on parent element,to write it here.
Here is the Code.

```css
.mobile-menu{
position:fixed;
width:70%;
height:100%;
background:white;
z-index:1000;
}
.mobile-menu ul{
top:10.2%;
position:relative;
color:black;
text-align:left;
font-weight:bold;
}
.mobile-menu li{
position:relative;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
padding-top:4%;
padding-bottom:4%;
}
.mobile-menu li:hover{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
.mobile-menu ul li ul{
display:none;
background:#fff;
padding:0;
border:none;
}
.mobile-menu ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
```

```html
     <div class="mobile-menu">
         <ul class="mobile-menu-ul">
           </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can not see the screesnshot and can you make your question more clear?

Comment: Now you can see it,sorry.

Comment: I can't see the snippet.

Comment: Update your snippet here. Can't see it.

Comment: I guess the submenu ul has a margin-top and so you can see the black background of the li. But it would be helpfully to inspect the DOM to say more.

Comment: Well i guess there is a problem with the site,or I'am stupid and don't know how to upload it.. Its uploaded for me,i mean i see the code in snippet.I put code into paste bin,if it not problem for you guys,there it is: http://pastebin.com/ECPjRb3U

Comment: it would be nice if u could provide live demo or url to actual problem so we  can have a look

Comment: http://shreddingnation.com/ there is my blog,which I am creating,i will leave this menu in front to have a look.Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of applying bgcolor to `li` add it to `a`

remove this code from ur css file

```
.mobile-menu li:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.mobile-menu li {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
}
```

and add this to ur css file

```
.mobile-menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4% 0;
}
.mobile-menu > ul> li:hover > a, .mobile-menu > ul> li:hover > .sub-menu > li:hover > a, .mobile-menu > ul .sub-menu  .sub-menu > li:hover > a{
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: glad I could help :)